# Relay SCP to server ? How?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

My Linux servers are behind a gateway server to which I ssh to get a menu :

```
# ssh expNoob@gateway01
   0 | root@srv01:SSH
   1 | root@srv02:SSH
   2 | root@srv03:SSH
```

and pick a server to land on..
I also can send files with SCP like this :

```
scp file.gz expNoob@gateway01:root@srv01:SSH:/tmp/
```

It works ! I have never seen such a syntax for SCP, man page says target is of the form : `user@server:path`, I shouldn't be able to "glue" such tokens to "beam" the file from server to server like this, but it works !
Do you know of such a syntax ? Is this dedicated software, or can this be achieved with standard ssh  config ??

Thx.

Comment: No such syntax. This is just an `ad hoc`shell script provided by your system manager to simplify your life, and to make sure no one lands on gateway01. It is easy enough to imagine how to write it, if you have any experience with the Bash shell and with ssh/scp.

Comment: Thx Marius, now that you explain it, it actually makes sense !